# max-height 100% overflowing parent

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a list-group using bootstrap, with a lot of items in it. I applied the following css rules to the id of my list-group div.

```
#my-listgroup {
    margin-top: 20px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
```

Now this div is wrapped in a couple of other divs, as shown below.

[image: markup of my issue.]

how do I make my listgroup not overflow my #body-content-menu div who has the following css rules, while still allowing this to be responsive.

```
#body-content-menu {
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #B21E15;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: `max-height: 100%;` needs a valid of `height` in CSS from its direct parent, else it is 100% of null (unknown value)

Comment: would `height:auto` work?

Comment: `height:auto`, is the defaut value , if it needs to be reset yes , else there's no need to declare it again, it is already active :) but it won't be any usable  values to be used for `height:XX%` or `max-height : XX%` for the children.

Comment: So how do I use percentages to make this work? If my container has `height:100%`, and my xth-descendent has `height:100%`, shouldn't it stop overflow it from overflowing?

Comment: The best you should do is to set a snippet with a working example of your issue (and eventually  link also a  jsfiddle or a codepen ), bits of CSS doesn't help much . your container ? direct parent is `.col-lg-12.col-sm-12` , does it have a known and static height set in CSS ?

Comment: Live link need for your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you must have a jquery link in you page(Maybe bootstrap add it to your page). Then you need to set an id for div `class="row"` for example `id="row` and another id for div `class="col-lg-12"` for example `id="col"`.

Now:

```
var realHeight = $('#col').height() - $('#row').height();
$('#my-listgroup').css('height', realHeight + 'px');
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<div id="col" style="height:100px;background-color:red;margin:100px;">
 <div id="row" style="height:40px;">div row</div>
 <select id="my-listgroup" size="4" name="ctl02" style="max-height: 100%;">
 
 <option value="item">item</option>
 <option value="item">item</option>
 <option value="item">item</option>
 <option value="item">item</option>
 <option value="item">item</option>
 <option value="item">item</option>

</select></div>
<script>
  var realHeight = $('#col').height() - $('#row').height();
    $('#my-listgroup').css('height', realHeight + 'px');
</script>
```

Comment: this did not fix it.

Comment: the edit still did not fix it. the overflow-y:scroll on the col just added a scrollbar outside of my listgroup, in the #body-content-menu.

Comment: It has scroll but still is overflow height?

Comment: yes, the scroll bar matches the same length as my listgroup

Comment: Can I see the page? Is it online? Your problem is about overflow height, Is it?

Comment: It isn't online. I can link you to my github page, however it's using .net mvc, so you won't get the full html.

Comment: my problem is about the listbox going outside of the container. So it is about overflow.

Comment: NO it does not help. But I.m sure there is an issue. When you set the parent div `overflow-y: scroll`, It means the children can not overflow in height.

Comment: I can post what is in the inspect element window, and post my style sheet. Would that help?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134851/discussion-between-farzin-kanzi-and-destructi6n).